# Navigation menu (with submenu tree) breaks in IE 6, IE7, IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I used navigation menu that shown in this [article](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu). It works in Mozilla, Chrome, Safari, Opera's main versions. But in IE6, IE7, IE8 it breaks. How can add/change css in the code in that article for IE 6-7-8 versions?

Comment: in which way your menu is broken? Could you better describe your issue and post a fiddle with the minimal code to reproduce it?

Comment: Menu was breaking, all sub menus was shown, but they should shown only on hover. I solved this issue just now. I replaced <nav> with <div>. It worked. thanks. <nav> not working in old IE versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of Internet Explorer (and other browsers) do not support the newer HTML5 elements (including `<nav>`). There is a javascript workaround in the form of [the HTML5 Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv).

> [The HTML5 Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) enables use of HTML5 sectioning elements in legacy Internet Explorer and provides basic HTML5 styling for Internet Explorer 6-9, Safari 4.x (and iPhone 3.x), and Firefox 3.x.

If you do not want a dependency on Javascript, you can fall back to using older HTML 4 elements with [appropriate ARIA landmark roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#landmark_roles), e.g. `<div class="nav" role="navigation">`.